# Why extra memory for one struct datatype?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

I have written a simple C code in which I have defined two struct datatypes dT0 and dT1. The dT0 datatype has one int elemnt (a) and one double element (r) whereas the datatype dT1 has two int elements (a and b) and a double element (r). Naturally I would think that the memory requirement for dT0 would be less than that of dT1 but to my surprise, when I try to print their sizes in main using sizeof(), I get the same memory requirement for both, that is 16. I was expecting 12 bytes for dT0 (4 for int and 8 for double) and 16 bytes for dT1 (8 for two ints and 8 for double). What am I missing?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct dType0
{
  int a;
  double r;
}dT0;

typedef struct dYype1
{
  int a,b;
  double r;
}dT1;

int main()
{
  printf("%d %d\n",sizeof(dT0),sizeof(dT1));
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: [Padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Comment: Compilers are allowed to put padding in between struct members for alignment purposes.